# Haproxy with multiple CA configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-api-gateway, haproxy

SSL newbie here, using haproxy 1.8, having a situation when I have 2 aws API Gateways pointing to the same proxy server and 2 clients certificates generated by api gateway itself assigned one to each gateways.

Now I have a haproxy server that I'm trying to configure in a way to only allow access from these 2 api gateways.

When I do it for api gateway only, meaning I only set the ca-file to a file containing 1 client certificate, it works just fine as expected but I don't know how to set both client certificates to be allowed.

so I have these files setup:

- **haproxy.pem** which contains

  - server cert issued by go daddy
  - private key
  - go daddy certs
- **api-gw.pem** first client cert which was copied from api gateway
- **api-gw2.pem** second client cert which was copied from api gateway
- **client-certs.crt** which is a concatenated version of *api-gw.pem* and *api-gw2.pem*

when I bind ssl like below for client cert, it works just fine:

```
bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem verify required ca-file /etc/haproxy/api-gw.pem
```

or

```
bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem verify required ca-file /etc/haproxy/api-gw2.pem
```

for each of the bindings above only the correct api gateway can access the proxy and the other one can't.

but when I do as below to allow both access the proxy server, it only allows the first client cert even though the file contains both:

```
bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy.pem verify required ca-file /etc/haproxy/client-certs.pem
```

As my knowledge is limited when it comes to certificates and ssl, I'm not sure if it would work to put multiple client certificates into one file but from what I've read in internet, it's suggested that way... I still don't know why wouldn't it work though.

**EDIT**
I Michael suggested, I put both client certs together using the

```
cat api-gw.pem api-gw2.pem > api-gw-combo.pem
```

and the combo file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....cert content for api-gw
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.....cert content for api-gw2
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

but same as my initial file `client-certs.crt`, haproxy still accepts the first cert only.

Comment: Inside `/etc/haproxy`, try combining the two pem files, e.g. `cat api-gw.pem api-gw2.pem > api-gw-combo.pem` and then set `ca-file /etc/haproxy/api-gw-combo.pem`.  Untested, but *if* you can do this, I suspect that will be the solution.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the `client-certs.crt` was created the same way but anyway I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: also when I do `cat`, it will add `^N` to the end of first cert's each line *(I have no idea why)* which I had to clear and also add the new line for the 2nd cert as well.

Comment: What exactly happened when it "didn't work?"  The docs say [`ca-file`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#5.1-ca-file) *"designates a PEM file from which to load CA certificates used to verify client's certificate."*  Note that "certificates" is plural.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I mean it only accepts the first ca and acts as the 2nd one doesn't exist. Is there any specific format it has to follow other than the normal PEM format with BEGIN & END tags?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I saw the documentation as well, that's what got me thinking that maybe something's wrong with my way of mergin certs. I'm gonna edit the question to add how the combo looks like

Comment: If this all works the way it seems like it should, then the way you are combining the certs seems correct.  TLS client auth (as I recall) means that the server sends the DNs of all recognized CAs in the TLS handshake.  This implies that you should be able to confirm that it really is listing both of them, using `openssl s_client`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I generated 2 self-signed certs **(with different common name)** and put them as a combo file together & attached into haproxy and it worked as expected but it still doesn't work when I put 2 api gw certs. Could it be because they both have a same common name? *(api gw always uses a same common name to generate its client certs)*

Answer (score 1):

Your config (about two client CA certificates in one file for SSL client authorization) for me is working fine:

```
bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/my-domain.pem ca-file /etc/haproxy/ssl/my_client_CA_bundle.crt verify required
```

But maybe it is working due for specific situation:

- HaProxy 2.2.X,
- in `my_client_CA_bundle.crt` file we have two Root CA for client verification,
- but both our CA for client verification are created using the same private key (maybe this is important difference from your problem?).

This config was used for a smooth transition to the new client's CA when the old one runs out.